# which encoding should i use

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Using SSIS we are extracting names and addresses from one system and providing them to a downstream system via a vendor specific file format that only accepts UTF-8, &  parses the data based on character positions, so it expects each row to be an exact length.

Many users have umlauts, apostrophes or accents in their names and addresses.
These characters do not translate well in UTF-8, showing up as xD3, xE1 and similar.

As one char is now replaced with 3, the row length is now incorrect and the upload fails.

Is there a way to represent  characters with accents & umlauts in UTF-8?

We can change them in the source system, but that means the spelling is now technically incorrect.

Comment: *"Is there a way to represent characters with accents & umlauts in UTF-8? "* What? UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode. In Unicode, you can represent *everything*, from Sumerian cuneiform to domino tiles, and all kind of other crazy U+1F4A9. Obviously, it can *also* represent umlauts. Your question is unclear. If your question is whether you can represent all Unicode code points in one byte - No (but you could try to use [some antediluvian single-byte-per-char encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646)).

Comment: "*a vendor specific file format that only accepts UTF-8, & parses the data based on character positions, so it expects each row to be an exact length*" - then it does NOT actually accept UTF-8, which is a variable-length encoding. It actually accepts ASCII instead, or at least ANSI, iow single-byte encodings, which UTF-8 is not. You might get away with using one of the various Latin encodings that support certain umlauts/accents and other non-ASCII characters. Also, consider transliterating certain Unicode characters, like apostrophes, to their ASCII equivalents

Comment: Character != byte. From what who have said, that misunderstanding is the problem. Who's saying the line lengths or character positions are wrong?

Comment: Hi.

You are correct, my understanding of the problem was very poor.
I have since realized the issue.

Data is stored in SQL Server varchar column which is some windows specific encoding.

If i convert this to Nvarchar it becomes UFT-16, sql server doesnt do UTF-8.

Using SSIS I converted to UTF-8 using a data transformation, specifying codepage 65001, and the same on the output file connection.

I now can get the data encoded in UTF8 in the extracted file.

Thanks for the advice all.